# How do I change state onClick?

Tags: reactjs, null, setstate

How do I set this function to null after setGenreObject state has successfully run? What I want is for the entire CategoryContainer to disappear onClick.

```
    <CardContainer>
{Object.keys(ClientPdfs).map((ageName, i) => (
                <Card
                  onClick={() => setGenreObject(ClientPdfs[ageName])}
                  key={i}>
                <CategoryContainer>
                  <Overlay />
                  <CategoryPhoto src={ClientPdfs[ageName].image} alt="ages"/>
                  <CategoryName>
                    {ClientPdfs[ageName].name}
                  </CategoryName>
                  </CategoryContainer>
                </Card>
              ))}
            </CardContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable setting it to null.
Let's call it card.

so: `let card = null`

then we can do some kind of check, e.g:

```js
if (!state.hasRun) {
  card = <Card>...</Card>
}
```

And then you return `{card}` as the result inside map function.

Comment: I'm not quite understanding this. The state is already set to null. I want it onClick to return to null. I may be wording this wrong to where I'm not making much sense. When it looks like this: `onClick={() => setGenreObject(null)}` changing the state is easy, but when it looks like this: `onClick={() => setGenreObject(ClientPdfs[ageName])}` I'm getting stuck on how to change the state to null after it's successfully run once.

Comment: Unless a change of state does not occur once the button is clicked, then it won't rerender. I'm not entirely sure what you mean if I'm honest, but eitherway to trigger to re-render (if that is what you are trying to achieve) you will need to change state.

I'm not sure what the `setGenreObject` is doing, but you need to ensure that there is a state change.

Could you not track the state and see what's happening and debug from there?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your CategoryContainer inside a bracket and execute it when there is a value present in the genreObject. Take a look at below example.

```
<CardContainer>
{Object.keys(ClientPdfs).map((ageName, i) => (
    <Card
      onClick={() => setGenreObject(ClientPdfs[ageName])}
      key={i}>
    {!genreObject && (
      <CategoryContainer>
      <Overlay />
      <CategoryPhoto src={ClientPdfs[ageName].image} alt="ages"/>
      <CategoryName>
        {ClientPdfs[ageName].name}
      </CategoryName>
      </CategoryContainer>
    )}
    </Card>
  ))}
</CardContainer>
```